# Por que o custo de complexidade de uma BFS é O(n+m)?

Tags: c++

Eu preciso mostrar que o custo para saber se existe um caminho entre dois vértices v e w é O(n²). Pra isso eu posso fazer uma BFS em um grafo, só que, o custo de uma bfs é O(n+m), mas eu não entendo por que tem esse "m", e também não sei como fazer a representação gráfica, mostrando as funções dominando assintoticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso depende...

Se você estiver usando uma lista de adjacências para representar o grafo, o algoritmo de busca em largura (BFS) terá complexidade O(V+A) sendo V o número de vértices e A o número de arestas.

Isso porque cada vértice será visitado uma vez e será marcado, ou seja, complexidade V. 
Para cada vértice você deve verificar todos os seus vizinhos para saber quais já estão marcados. O número de vizinhos é o número de arestas que ele está conectado. Se você fizer isso pra todos os vértices esta parte do código será executado 2*A vezes, pois a soma do número de arestas de cada vértice dá 2 vezes o número total de arestas.

Portanto você vai executar V+2A iterações no seu código, mas como em notação big-O as constantes são desprezadas você teria complexidade O(V+A).

Já se você estiver usando uma matriz de adjacências para representar o seu grafo, o algoritmo vai ter complexidade O(V²). Isto porque para cada vértice você terá que iterar em todos os vértices para olhar na matriz e saber se o vértice é um vizinho ou não.

Comment: Muito obrigado Sérgio! Agora sim entendi. Você sabe como ficara uma representação gráfica de O(n+m)?

Comment: Não sei, acho que a melhor forma de representação vai depender do caso. Eu colocaria o eixo y como número de operações e o eixo x como n+m daí ficaria um gráfico linear.